# How to get data along with columns in data viewer in ssis

Tags: ssis

After adding data viewer between two transformations in my SSIS project the output will be like below image.

But after executing my SSIS package I am getting only columns data i.E country, item_type, total_value, sales_count and I am not getting total records data.

Is there any settings in SSIS package to get the total records set after execution?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post in all caps. It is very annoying.

Comment: Thank you for fixing that. Much better!

Comment: I fixed your caps lock for you - next time, please turn the caps lock off before writing your question. I promise that it will make people far more likely to help you if it doesn't feel like you're yelling at them.

Comment: @Anji is it that you want to see all the columns in the flow or all the rows?